# ASP.net MVC routing with optional first parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, optional-parameters

I need to provide following functionality for one of the web sites.

http://www.example.com/**[sponsor]**/{controller}/{action}

Depending on the [sponsor], the web page has to be customized.

I tried combination of registering the routes with Application_Start and Session_Start but not able to get it working.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes, string sponsor)
{
        if (routes[sponsor] == null)
    {
      routes.MapRoute(
     sponsor, // Route name
     sponsor + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
     );
    }
}
```

Also, the default behavior without **[sponsor]** should also function.
Can someone please let me know if it is technically feasible to have an optional first parameter in the MVC3 URL. If yes, please share the implementation. Thank you.

---

**Updated Code**
After making the changes as suggested by *Sergey Kudriavtsev*, the code works when  value is given. 
If  name is not provided then MVC does not route to the controller/action.

Note that this works only for the home controller (both  and non-sponsor). For other controllers/actions, even when sponsor parameter is specified it is not routing.

Please suggest what has to be modified.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
             "SponsorRoute",
             "{sponsor}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "NonSponsorRoute",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, sponsor = string.Empty }
        );
    }
```

**Action Method**

```
public ActionResult Index(string sponsor)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your case `sponsor` should not be treated as a constant part of URL, but as a variable part.

In Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
...
     routes.MapRoute(
     "SponsorRoute",
     "{sponsor}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
     routes.MapRoute(
     "NonSponsorRoute",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, sponsor=string.Empty }
     );

...
}
```

In your controllers, for example, HomeController.cs:

```
namespace YourWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string sponsor)
        {
            // Here you can do any pre-processing depending on sponsor value, including redirects etc.
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that type of this parameter will always be `System.String` and the name of route template component `{sponsor}` must exactly match the name of action parameter `string sponsor` in your controllers.

UPD: Added second route for non-sponsor case.

Please note that such setup will complicate your logic, because you might confuse different urls, for example URL

http://www.example.com/a/b/c

could be matched by both routes: first one will have sponsor=a, controller=b and action=c; second one will have controller=a, action=b and id=c.

This situation can be avoided if you specify more strict requirements to URLs - for example, you may want IDs to be numerical only. Restrictions are specified in fourth parameter of `routes.MapRoute()` function.

Another approach for disambiguation is specifying separate routes for all of your controllers (usually you won't have much of them in your app) before generic route for sponsors.

UPD:

Most straightforward yet least maintainable way to distinguish between sponsor and non-sponsor routes is specifying controller-specific routes, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
...
     routes.MapRoute(
     "HomeRoute",
     "Home/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, sponsor=string.Empty }
     );
     routes.MapRoute(
     "AccountRoute",
     "Account/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, sponsor=string.Empty }
     );

     ...

     routes.MapRoute(
     "SponsorRoute",
     "{sponsor}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );

...
}
```

Note that here all controller-specific routes must be added **before** SponsorRoute.

More complex yet more clean way is implementing RouteConstraints for sponsor and controller names as described in answer from @counsellorben.

Comment: thanks for the reply. [sponsor] should be an optional parameter. With {sponsor}/{controller}/{action}/{id}, the url home/index shall be treated as [home == sponsor]/[index == controller] which shall throw resource not found exception.

Comment: Then you will need two separate routes - one with {sponsor}, another one without it, I'll edit my answer a bit...

Comment: How many controllers do you have? Can you give the list of their names?

Comment: There are more than 7-8 controllers. If you can suggest how to make it functioning for one, I will modify others. Example controller: 1. Home 2. Account ....

Comment: Updated my answer. A simple solution I've added would be more or less OK for 7-8 controllers, but you should keep in mind that for every controller added later you will have to add another controller-specific route. 
If you prefer to have a bit more work now to save time later then you should implement @counsellorben's answer

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I've resolved this issue using the following two routers:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MultiCulture",
        url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(CultureFactory.All.Select(item => item.UrlPrefix).ToArray()) }
    ).RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
  }
}
```

Where `CultureConstraint` class looks like below:

```
public class CultureConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
  private readonly string[] values;

  public CultureConstraint(params string[] values)
  {
    this.values = values;
  }

  public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteDirection routeDirection)
  {
    string value = routeValues[parameterName].ToString();

    return this.values.Contains(value);
  }
}
```

And `MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler` like this:

```
public class MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
  protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
  {
    var culture = CultureManager.GetCulture(requestContext.RouteData);

    if (culture != null)
    {
      var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture.Name);

      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
    }

    return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
  }
}
```

Comment: `CultureFactory.All` returns a list of culture codes like "de", "en", "pl", etc., I guess?!

Comment: @UweKeim Sorry, it's too late, but yes, you're right. It returns collection of List<Culture>.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to adding a second route before the default route, as Sergey said in his answer, you also must add a `RouteConstraint` to the initial route, to enforce that the `{sponsor}` token is the name of a valid sponsor.

You can use the RouteConstraint in this answer:  [Asp.Net Custom Routing and custom routing and add category before controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713590/asp-net-custom-routing-and-custom-routing-and-add-category-before-controller/7715238#7715238)

Remember that you must also enforce a rule that a sponsor name cannot be the same as any of your controller names.

Answer (score 1):

i will show you in simple example you don't have to change in **Route.config.cs**
only you have to do in **Route.config.cs** just put in

**Optional URI Parameters First and Default Values**

**Route.config.cs**

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

**Controller**

```
[Route("{Name}/Controller/ActionName")]
        public ActionResult Details(string Name)
        {            

              // some code here 

            return View();
        }
```

**Results**

**localhost:2345/Name/controllername/actionname/id(optional)**