# Prepend a custom parameter before {controller} in ASP.NET WebApi route

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to create a route template for Owin WebApi like this:

```
cfg.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "{myparam}/{controller}/{action}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Because I have controllers defined that need a parameter before the controller selection.

I have tried to remove the parameter and set it into RoutePrefixAttribute on controller but it doesn't work.

{controller} must be the first dynamic parameter of the route?

Answer (score 1):

I would use some form of attribute based routing to go to different controllers based on {myparam}.

First controller:

`[Route("param1/customer/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int id) { ... }`

Second controller:

`[Route("param2/customer/{id}")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int id) { ... }`

More information can be found here: [Attribute Based WebAPI Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Sorry but {myparam} is not known at compile time, it's dynamic (like a category name, but it's not like this).

Comment: I would take a look here then, [routing with optional first parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310815/asp-net-mvc-routing-with-optional-first-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Delete RoutePrefix attribute and set the first parameter dynamic in your action Route attribute like the example below:

```
[HttpGet, Route("{myparam}/books/{bookId:int:min(1)}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string myparam, int bookId)
{
...
}
```

Comment: You didn't answer question.  How do you configure so it works.