# How to display only name in url instead of id in mvc.net using routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am getting url like `http://localhost:49671/TestRoutes/Display?f=hi&i=2`

I want it like `http://localhost:49671/TestRoutes/Display/hi`

I call it from Index method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? e )
{
    //  return View("Display", new { f = "hi", i = 2 });
    return RedirectToAction("Display", new { f = "hi", i = 2 });
}
```

Index view

```
@model Try.Models.TestRoutes
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    Model.e = 5 ; 
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Display Action method

```
// [Route("TestRoutes/{s}")]
public ActionResult Display(string s, int i)
{
    return View(); 
}
```

Route config file

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Professional", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "TestRoutes", action = "Display", s = UrlParameter.Optional, i = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =   UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Comment: You route definitions need to match the parameter names - `"TestRoutes/Display/{s}/{i}"` (and only the last parameter can be `UrlParameter.Optional`)

Comment: I am unable to code it properly, Can I use  attributes instead of Maproute thing?

Comment: What is not working? It just needs to be `routes.MapRoute(name: "Professional", url: "TestRoutes/Display/{s}/{i}", new { controller = "TestRoutes", action = "Display" });`. But in your `Index()` method it needs to be `return RedirectToAction("Display", new { s = "hi", i = 2 });` (not `f`)

Comment: I am so sorry, I am stretching it a lot but again it's giving me an error " Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified" Am I missing basics of routing ?

Comment: Sorry, I left of the `defauts:` in front of `new { ....`

Comment: Jesus! I am so sorry for being stupid. I shouldn't have asked that one.

Comment: Thanks ! now it's like " http://localhost:49671/TestRoutes/Display/hi/2" Can I remove id from url and keep only name ?

Comment: What `id`? Your parameters are `s` and `i`. Do you mean you want to remove the `i` (`2`) value? If so just add `i = UrlParameter.Optional` and use `return RedirectToAction("Display", new { s = "hi" });` But why are you parameters named `s` and `i` when clearly they mean `name` and `id`?

Comment: Sorry to use such parameter names , Well, I want to pass id but I don't want it should be displayed on url

Comment: And how would you expect the value of `i` to be know in the `Display()` method if you don't pass it to the method :) (you could always use `Session` and retrieve it but that would be crazy)

Comment: Yup, Thanks for all your replies. I am glad. I wish if I encounter another issues, you'll help me out :P

Comment: I wanted to mark that answer as correct but it's a comment.

Comment: I have added the answer now :)

Comment: [Visit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310815/asp-net-mvc-routing-with-optional-first-parameter/45311947#45311947) i hope it will helps you a lot in simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your route definition to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Professional",
    url: "TestRoutes/Display/{s}/{i}",
    default: new { controller = "TestRoutes", action = "Display", i = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

so that the names of the placeholders match the names of the parameters in your method. Note also that only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional` (otherwise the `RoutingEngine` cannot match up the segments and the values will be added as query string parameters, not route values)

Then you need to change the controller method to match the route/method parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? e )
{
    return RedirectToAction("Display", new { s = "hi", i = 2 }); // s not f
}
```

Comment: Default before new :)

Comment: Lazy cut and paste :)

Comment: I didn't do it intentionally, I guess it was a click by mistake, I didn't even realize when did I click. So sorry.

Comment: Hey Stephen, I'd like to ask questions which are not related to this thread but others which you've put on hold, I hope you won't mind.

Comment: @Nil, Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What questions are your referring to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820251/how-to-program-search-filter-for-online-shopping-portal-using-mvc-net-and-linq  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808729/how-to-design-a-layout-for-shopping-portal-using-mvc-net I'd like your opinion about these questions. I am doing the same. I'd be glad if you could guide me.

Comment: @Nil, both those questions are far too broad for SO. I'll add some notes to them I will not re-open them.

Comment: Should I add exact specification of my problem ?

Comment: Yes, Ask a question, but state exactly what your trying to achieve, the code for it and indicate what is not working (but if you just wanting some guidelines for the best way to do something, then that is off-topic and the question will be closed)

Answer (score 0):

change your route as 
    routes.MapRoute(
    "Professional", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
     controller = "TestRoutes",
     action = "Display"
    } // Parameter defaults
    );

and your action as

```
public ActionResult Display(string name)
{
     //action goes here
}
```

Comment: I may require id property for further operations. But even if I remove it, I am not able to see any changes in the url. If possible to you can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Then add one more attribute in route url for example        routes.MapRoute("Professional", "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}",
                new {controller = "TestRoutes",
                     action = "Display",
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional}, and action like public ActionResult Display(string name, int? id){ // action goes here}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the maproute code:
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Professional", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "TestRoutes", action = "Display", s = UrlParameter.Optional, i = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
Use attribute routing code:
    [Route("TestRoutes/{s}/{i?}")]
    public ActionResult Display(string s, int? i)
    {
        return View(); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using Attribute Routing. You can control your routes easier with attribute routing.

Firstly change your RouteConfig.cs like that:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
}
```

After that change your controller files like that:

```
namespace YourProjectName.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Home")]
    [Route("{action}/{id=0}")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("ChangeAddress/{addressID}")]
        public ActionResult ChangeAddress(int addressID)
        {
            //your codes to change address
        }
}
```

You can also learn more about Attribute Routing in this post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am not getting your solution. Do you mean I should write diff controller for routing?

Comment: No, **RouteConfig.cs** is under "App_Start" folder in your MVC project. If you want to use Attribute Routing, you have to change your RouteConfig.cs content and your other controllers like in my post. I think Attribute Routing is a more flexible solution than Convention Routing. And you can easily control your routes.

Comment: Attribute routing isn't working for me ( I am unable to use it, I meant) I get default url with id? etc

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to put the proper route before the default route, as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MyRouteName", url: "Id", defaults: new { controller= "Home", action = "Index",id= Id });
```

Default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",id= Id }
);
```