# Is it possible to show name instead of id in url by using asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

in asp.net mvc c# crud operation (e.g create, update, remove and detail)
i get row by id on update and detail.
when i get row by id for update, id show on url.
I m creating blog website in asp.net mvc c#
blog table has column like blogId, blogTitle, blogDetail etc...

My question is this i want to get row by blogid but show blogTitle on url

Comment: You need to configure routes for your endpoints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display only name in url instead of id in mvc.net using routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638880/how-to-display-only-name-in-url-instead-of-id-in-mvc-net-using-routing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your blogTitle is unique or you can create slug from your blog title and you can use that

1# you need to change and fix your route in RouteConfig.cs
typically the id parameter needs to be replace with blogTitle

and that's it. it will land you to right blogTitle or slug you have created.

Hope this helps.

Comment: id parameter should not be replaced, instead, it needs to be set to optional.