# WebApi ignores defaults from route definition template

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm fighting with solution for WebApi routes where for not provided values for tokens in the route template I'd like to have them o be auto-populated with defaults.

My route declaration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "LandingPage Route",
           routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "LandingPageCommon",
               id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional,
               version = ApiVersions.None,
               logging = true
           },
           constraints: new
           {
               version = new ApiVersionRouteConstraint()
           }
       //  handler: apiVersionHandler
       );
```

Now I'm making 2 calls via Postman:

1) working as expected (I'm given with proper entity) for GET **/api/v3/LandingPageCommon/886858**

- {version} -> v3
- {controller} -> LandingPageCommon
- {id} -> 886858

2) not working for GET **/api/LandingPageCommon/886858**

- {version} -> not provided so should be taken form 'defaults' from declaration -> 'none'
- {controller} -> LandingPageCommon
- {id} -> 886858

I've created custom RouteConstraint to guard {version} parameter. While debugging the 2nd call I see that, route tokens are not properly set up ({version} -> {controller} and {controller} -> {id}):

[image: route parameters]

At the sime time I see the defaults in the route declaration:

[image: route defaults]

Why for the 2nd call {version} is not set to its default value?
Thanks

Comment: problem is how will engine know which route to call in second scenario, i don't think this is a feasible route you are looking for, you cannot have a default value in between a route. check this answer which talks about MVC route but same rules apply for API routing too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310815/asp-net-mvc-routing-with-optional-first-parameter

Comment: You pointed to right direction. Thanks Prashant