# asp.net mvc routing, with area as parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a website for multiple organizations. For example, people could go to mydomain.com/org1/home/index or mydomain.com/org2/home/index.

What I am trying to do is have the following routing,

mydomain.com/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}

I can't figure out how to do this, and frankly not even sure how to even start setting up my routing. I want to be able to access {area} string in order to decide which images to display, what text etc.

I hope I'm making sense with what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
defaults: new {
controller = "Home",
action = "Index",
id = UrlParameter.Optional,
area = UrlParameter.Optional
);
```

Your Home controller will look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string area, string id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! That definitely solves that problem. And now I'm faced with another since this is not always the case, i.e. having the {area} parameter. So now, when I go to /Account/Login it gives error. If I add a string before like this: /foo/Account/Login it takes me to the login page.

I realize this is another problem. What I did is I used the route you gave me as the first "customRoute" and then the default route is declared after that.

Do you know how to solve this? Or should I perhaps post another question?

Comment: You can add `routes.MapRoute(
name: "Account",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
defaults: new {
controller = "Account",
action = "Login",
id = UrlParameter.Optional
);` just before the "Default" route up top

Comment: So now I have two routes, "Default" and "Account". If "Account" route is up top, I'm not able to access mydomain.com/foo/home/index even if HomeController has Index(string area), it simply gives me an error. If I place "Default" up top, I am able to access mydomain.com/foo/home/index, works great but I am also able to access other controllers/actions where I don't want to. For example, I have a DivisionsController with ActionResult Index(). Now I am able to call mydomain.com/foo/divisions/index and it returns the same page as if I wrote mydomain.com/divisions/index. I don't want that...

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713590/asp-net-custom-routing-and-custom-routing-and-add-category-before-controller/7715238#7715238) solution:

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm after. Thanks a lot for your help! I voted you up but I'm too young in here for it to count :)